# concatenating hex numbers in perl

Tags: perl, hex

I have say two hex numbers

```
A[2:0] : 0x3
B[3:0] : 0x2
```

My aim is to combine the above two values into a single variable : C [6:0] : 0x23  i.e just concatenating the values of A & B.

Can someone please help me how do I achieve this using perl.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the whole point of 'hex'. It's a number format. Concatenating it doesn't make any sense. You can concatenate two strings in perl using `$str1 . $str2`. But there's no mathematical operation where `2 + 3 = 35` which is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to shift first number by four places left (`* 0x10`), and add second to it

```
my $A=0x2;
my $B=0x3;

my $C = ($A <<4) +$B;
printf("%x", $C);
```

output

```
23
```

Comment: hi mpapec : so this output 23 will be a hexadecimal no. ? i.e it is 0x23 ?

Comment: When I am just assigning $C  to another variable $D i.e. $D = "0x$C ";  I am getting the output as 0x35, so is there a way I can assign this 0x23 to another variable ?

Comment: Yes, `$D = $C;`! `print` output is always decimal unless you're using `printf("%x", $NUMBER);` or similar.